# Tcl write to textfile in the last row

Tags: file, tcl, tk-toolkit, data-manipulation

i want to complete an existing Textfile if the user click on yes by a Dialog.
The actual code overwrite the existing file!

```
set answer [tk_messageBox -message "file already exists, do you want to add more?" -title "Configuration Check" -type yesno -parent .example1]
    case $answer {
    yes {
     set fid [open $::filename2/testfile.txt w]
     puts $fid "last row"
    close $fid
```

Is there any idea to go to the last existing row and to complete the file?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the file using access of `w` which causes the file to be truncated if it exists and created if it does not exist.  What you need to do is open the file with access of `a` or `a+`, the first opens an existing file and positions the file so you are writing at the end, the second does the same but creates the file if it doesn't exist.

```
set fid [open $::filename2/testfile.txt a+]
```

Is probably what you need.

Alternatively look at the `seek` and `tell` commands, these allow you to change the position in an opened file,

Comment: In append mode, you can _only_ append when you write (very useful for logs). Some ways of opening things require use of POSIX style modes.